# Could the USA be banned from the United Nations?

Tags: united-states, punishment, laws-of-war

The USA has been accused of starting wars by false flag operations since [the Maine](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Maine_(ACR-1)).

Some USA agencies linked to the CIA have admitted using covert means to start wars such us [The Washington Institute for Near East Policy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Institute_for_Near_East_Policy). This is an American think tank who is researching some programs all based on the middle east. This think tank have some former government officers including [R.James Woolsey Jr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._James_Woolsey_Jr.) **former CIA director**.

Years ago [Dr. Patrick Clawson](http://www.washingtoninstitute.org/experts/view/clawson-patrick) director of research said in a press conference:

> I frankly think crisis initiation is really tough, and it's hard for me to see how the United States President can get us to war with Iran...

[Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB6qSX8rVeY)

Later he talks about many questionable American wars that could have started by false flag operations.

> ...we are in the game of using covert means against the Iranians...

This man also appears on the BBC and many other talk shows.

Knowing that the USA spends more money on the military than the next 9 countries of the list combined ([ref here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_military_expenditures)) and 9/11 is being investigated by as a possible false flag operation. [(ref here)](https://www.ae911truth.org/) and [here](https://lawyerscommitteefor9-11inquiry.org/). And the CIA has done many controversial operations installing and removing leaders all over the world.

**Would it be possible to start sanctions against the USA or even ban them from the United Nations?**

Comment: Is it *necessary* to accompany every question you ask here with a lot of random opinion about world affairs? I am not going to stop you from doing it, but these opinions does not seem in any way relevant information for answering your questions, and I quite frankly think they make you look like you have some screw loose.

Comment: In fact all the whole thing sounds more like some kind of (very amateur) PR campaign for 9/11 conspiracy theories; this same user has spammed politics.SE too. https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/20963/pbxman

Comment: **Not spamming**. I'm using facts that are checked and i'm adding links. If you don't want to investigate them or accept them because of personal reasons is a different matter.

Comment: But these facts have absolutely no more *relevance* to the question than, for example, facts about the merits of some erectile dysfunction remedy. The latter would most certainly resulted in deletion for being spam.

Comment: @FreeRadical Not at all. I'm posing possible and credible scenarios in which this case could happen. If it's accepted that the USA is carrying out this kind of operations to disturb **world peace** for economic reasons this ban could happen.

Comment: @SJuan76 I'm not pro conspiracy theories. I'm pro **truth&justice** like it or not there are 3000 architects and engineers who are looking for exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This follows article 6 of the UN Charter:

> A Member of the United Nations which has persistently violated the Principles contained in the present Charter may be expelled from the Organization by the General Assembly upon the recommendation of the Security Council.

Comment: Except ... the USA has veto power on the Security Council so the Security Council will never make the recommendation

Comment: @DaleM It may be possible to strip the US of that seat first.

Comment: The US has a permanent seat on the Security Council. The UN Security Council is a joke in practice.

Comment: @DaleM The General Assembly could replace the current American state with another American state. This would effectively remove the current United States from the United Nations Security Council in the same way that the Republic of China was removed from the Security Council in 1971.

Comment: @Flux except the security council has to ratify new members and the US has a veto. The replacement of ROC with PRC was at the behest of both and it was the US position that prevented it for many years.

Comment: The Security Council _liberum veto_ does not apply when the matter under discussion involves a member of the Security Council itself.